# Raspberry pi not giving audio output

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pydub

I want to play an audio file on my raspberry pi. So far I have used PyAudio, PyDub and Pygame but none of theme work. I also used `omxplayer` to play the audio file and the speaker worked which means that raspberry pi is able to detect the speaker attached. So I don't understand what's the problem with code since it doesn't even throw any errors.

For pygame:

```
from pygame import mixer
import time
mixer.init()


mixer.music.load('Applause/previewand the winner is.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(2)
mixer.music.stop()
```

For pydub

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from pydub import effects

music = AudioSegment.from_mp3('<File>')
play(music)
```

Python version : `3.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("file_name.mp3")

pygame.mixer.music.play(0,0.0) #The parameters are the loops and the time the audio should start from.
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Okay I will try this out and see if it works.

Comment: Do you have any alternate solution?

Comment: I am sorry but no. Well the [pygame website](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) does list that the program may crash with `.mp3` files in Debian Based system and RaspberryPiOS (Raspbian) is a Debian distro. The website asks to try OGG instead